# Ant Build File and Libraries

Tags: java, swing, ant, build

I have tried the numerous ways of trying to include the dependent libraries.

My project depends on the:

appframework-1.03.jar, swing-worker.jar and swing-layout jars

This is my build file:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <project name="IvleFileSync" default="dist" basedir=".">
            <description>
                simple example build file
            </description>
          <!-- set global properties for this build -->
          <property name="src" location="src"/>
          <property name="build" location="build"/>
          <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>

        <path id="files-classpath">
            <fileset dir="/usr/lib" >
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>

          <target name="init">
            <!-- Create the time stamp -->
            <tstamp/>
            <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
            <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
          </target>

          <target name="compile" depends="init"
                description="compile the source " >
            <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
            <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="files-classpath" />
                <path location="/usr/lib/swing-layout-1.0.3.jar"/>
                <path location="/usr/lib/swing-worker-1.1.jar"/>
                <path location="/usr/lib/appframework-1.03.jar"/>
            </classpath>

           </target>

          <target name="dist" depends="compile"
                description="generate the distribution" >
            <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
            <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

            <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
            <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/IvleFileSync-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
          </target>

          <target name="clean"
                description="clean up" >
            <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
            <delete dir="${build}"/>
```

However am not able to compile the sources

It always throws the package org.jdesktop.application does not exist error.

I have put all my jars under "/usr/lib"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You closed the javac task before defining its classpath:

```
 <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
 <classpath>...
                                          ^-- javac is closed here.
```

Replace it with

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}">
    <classpath>...</classpath>
</javac>
```

And there's no need to add the jars twice to the classpath. You include them once using `<path refid=`, and then a second time by listing the jars.